# Visualización ListView - ViewCell cortada en Android (.Net MAUI - Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: android, .net, android-listview, visual-studio-2022, maui

Estoy realizando pruebas sencillas con el control ListView de .NET MAUI y me está surgiendo un problema al que no encuentro solución.

En Windows muestra la ListView sin problemas el ViewCell adapta su tamaño al contenido y se pinta correctamente:

[image: imagen de la ejecución "Windows Machine"]

Sin embargo cuando lanzo la app en mi dispositivo local android las celdas del ListView salen cortadas:

[image: app en dispositivo android]

He probado a modificar el "Height" del ViewCell, el StackLayout, meter las labels en un grid o en un Frame. Pero nada da resultado. En android siempre me corta el ViewCell. ¿A alguien mas le pasa esto?

Os muestro el código utilizado en el xaml y como hago la carga del ListView:

```
public partial class pag_prueba_listview: ContentPage {
  public pag_prueba_listview() {
    InitializeComponent();
    var items = new List <
      LotesAlmacen > ();
    items.Add(new LotesAlmacen {
      Material = "Material1", Cantidad = "Cantidad1", UM = "UM1", Lote = "Lote1", Nemo = "Nemo1", Descripción = "Descripción1"
    });
    items.Add(new LotesAlmacen {
      Material = "Material2", Cantidad = "Cantidad2", UM = "UM2", Lote = "Lote2", Nemo = "Nemo2", Descripción = "Descripción2"
    });
    items.Add(new LotesAlmacen {
      Material = "Material3", Cantidad = "Cantidad3", UM = "UM3", Lote = "Lote3", Nemo = "Nemo3", Descripción = "Descripción3"
    });
    items.Add(new LotesAlmacen {
      Material
        = "Material4", Cantidad = "Cantidad4", UM = "UM4", Lote = "Lote4", Nemo = "Nemo4", Descripción = "Descripción4"
    });
    items.Add(new LotesAlmacen {
      Material = "Material5", Cantidad = "Cantidad5", UM = "UM5", Lote = "Lote5", Nemo = "Nemo5", Descripción = "Descripción5"
    });
    items.Add(new LotesAlmacen {
      Material = "Material6", Cantidad = "Cantidad6", UM = "UM6", Lote = "Lote6", Nemo = "Nemo6", Descripción = "Descripción6"
    });
    items.Add(new LotesAlmacen {
      Material = "Material7", Cantidad = "Cantidad7",
        UM = "UM7", Lote = "Lote7", Nemo = "Nemo7", Descripción = "Descripción7"
    });
    items.Add(new LotesAlmacen {
      Material = "Material8", Cantidad = "Cantidad8", UM = "UM8", Lote = "Lote8", Nemo = "Nemo8", Descripción = "Descripción8"
    });
    items.Add(new LotesAlmacen {
      Material = "Material9", Cantidad = "Cantidad9", UM = "UM9", Lote = "Lote9", Nemo = "Nemo9", Descripción = "Descripción9"
    });
    items.Add(new LotesAlmacen {
      Material = "Material10", Cantidad = "Cantidad10", UM = "UM10", Lote = "Lote10", Nemo = "Nemo10",
        Descripción = "Descripción10"
    });
    listview.ItemsSource = items;
  }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="eversia_movil.Paginas.pag_prueba_listview" Title="pag_prueba_listview">

  <ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout>

      <ListView x:Name="listview">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell Height="300">
              <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">

                <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Lote}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Nemo}" FontAttributes="Italic" />
                <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Descripción}" />
                <Label Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Cantidad}" />
              </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>


    </VerticalStackLayout>
  </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pues al final encontré la solución repasando la documentación de microsoft sobre el ListView:

[Control ListView MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview?view=net-maui-7.0)

La respuesta siempre estuvo ahí, pero era poco intuitiva y no veía por que solo ocurría en android y no en windows (y sigo sin verlo):

**HasUnevenRows**, de tipo bool, indica si los elementos de la lista pueden tener filas de diferentes alturas. El valor predeterminado de esta propiedad es false.

**RowHeight**, de tipo int, determina el alto de cada fila cuando HasUnevenRows es false.

Pues eso, poniendo la propiedad **HasUnevenRows** a true, problema resuelto (o ampliando lo necesario el **RowHeight**).

Espero que quien se encuentre en este trance de con esta pregunta/respuesta lo antes posible. ¡Un saludo!